# Fluent ui Stack component makes PrimaryButton fill all the horizontal space available. How to make it shrink to fit

Tags: reactjs, electron, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

When I put a PrimaryButton inside a Stack component from fluent ui, button is rendered as follows in an electron app. How to make it shrink to fit?

[image]

Code for this is as follows

```html
return (
        <Stack grow={false}>
        <PrimaryButton text="Download Instruments" onClick={downloadInstruments} />
        </Stack>
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stack` component has default `width: auto` which means use `width` of parent element. But if you put `Stack.Item` over `PrimaryButton` everything will fit as you wish:

```
<Stack>
  <Stack.Item>
    <PrimaryButton text="Download Instruments" onClick={downloadInstruments} />
  </Stack.Item>
<Stack>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/bGRJMOr) working example.

> A Stack is a container-type component that abstracts the implementation of a flexbox in order to define the layout of its children components.

Proper way to use `Stack` is when you have multiple child elements. There is no point to put `Stack` over one element.

[Stack documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui/#/controls/web/stack) and working examples.